# How to pipe airodump-ng output to a jar file

Tags: java, terminal, pipe, stdout, stdin

Normally airodump-ng runs on a terminal window until I terminate the process. It also writes to a file which I open, parse, get what I need then repeat in a five second interval in the jarfile.

I'm wondering if this could be done with directly piping the output of the airodump-ng to a jar since all the I/O operations seem like overkill. Such as ;

```
 airodump-ng mon0 | java -jar jarfile.jar
```

Also note that i've tried to open the jar process in another terminal with

```
airodump-ng mon0 | gnome-terminal -e "java -jar jarfile.jar"
```

but still it prints out nothing. In the main method of the jarfile I've tried to do

```
while (true) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println(in.next());
}
```

but i think i'm on the wrong track. Should i use BufferedReader or something like that?